# Import file named by string in variable

Tags: python

If one of my python files is called `hello.py`, is there a way to import it to my other python file, called `main.py`, in the following way:

**main.py**

```
name = "hello"
import name
```

I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'name'

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
import importlib

importlib.import_module(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Other create python project. for example answer.py in this import hello.py